# Next.js - Type error: Cannot find name 'StaticImageData'

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

I am trying to push my code to Vercel, it fails in the build steps when checking the validity of the types.

This is the full error received:

```
info  - Checking validity of types...
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.d.ts:19:14
Type error: Cannot find name 'StaticImageData'.
```

I tried rolling back the Next.js version to 11, which didn’t work.

Edit:

I found this similar Github issue however it doesn’t seem to have been much help.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29788

Comment: Did you try importing that Type from Next? `import { StaticImageData } from "next/image"`

Answer (score 7):

As of February 16th 2022 this has been fixed, now you can just import `StaticImageData` like so:

```
import { StaticImageData } from "next/image"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily create a global type until the issue is resolved like so:

`global-types.d.ts`

```
export {};
declare global {
  type StaticImageData = {
    src: string
    height: number
    width: number
    blurDataURL?: string
  };
}
```

Then reference it as the first item in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"include": ["./global-types.d.ts","next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
```

Once they fix the issue, remove the reference.

Comment: This did not work for me. Still get the same error as OP.

Comment: This worked for me.. but I didn't have to create a separate "global" types declaration file.. I simply put `type StaticImageData = { src: string; height: number; width: number; blurDataURL?: string; }` in the same TS file with the calling script. Then, I set my interface Props to handle it: `src?: string | StaticImageData`